# React route with parameter

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to follow this article:
https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params

And I have created following:

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/:token" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
);
```

When I add :token my router does not work anymore. Am I missing something here? Should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `/:token` also matches `/page` and `/page2`. Reorder your routes so that `/:token` is at the end. Doing this will ensure that if the route matches `/page1` or `/page2` they are preferred and rendered over `/:token`

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        <Route exact path="/:token" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Worked. Not sure however why that does match two first, but I will go do some reading on it. Appreciated.

Comment: :token is meant to be a wildcard param meaning it will match anything that comes in after `/` , hence page1 and page2 are also matched by it. Anyways glad to have helped